# Proof that if composition of a curve $\gamma$ and a regular surface is a regular curve, than the curve $\gamma$ is regular

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

I have a curve $\gamma : A \subset \mathbb{R} \to D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and a regular surface $ S:D \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. Their composition $S \circ \gamma$ is a regular curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Can I state that $\gamma$ is a regular curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because $\gamma$ is the composition of a diffeomorphism $S(D) \rightarrow D$ with a regular curve.

Comment: As far as I understand, diffeomorphism imlies that  $S \rightarrow D$ is a bijection. But why is it a bijection?

Comment: @zoosporangiophore Because $S: D \rightarrow S(D)$ is a bijection

Comment: As far as I know, surface parametrizations are required to be injective, so they are bijections onto their image.